# How to catch moment when third part bean destroyed?

Tags: java, spring

xml configuration:

```
<bean id="str" class="java.lang.String">
  <constructor-arg value="string_1"/>
</bean>
```

I want to catch(hook) moment of creation and destroying of this bean ?

Comment: Can you alter the source code of SomeClass ?

Comment: You should probably explain why you'd create a bean that's just a String. Between String interning in Java and the extensive support for property management in Spring, the example looks contrived and the quality of the answers you get are going to be similarly wonky.

Comment: String is example. any final class.

Answer (score 1):

Use method annotaded with `@PostConstruct` and `@PostDestroy` in class that extends `SomeClass`.

Comment: But if is it String bean?(final class)

Comment: @gstackoverflow then you must create wrapper class that `HAS-A` reference to final class.

Answer (score 0):

Lifecycle callbacks:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lifecycle

@PostContruct and @PreDestroy annotations:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-postconstruct-and-predestroy-annotations

You can also implement your own BeanPostProcessor:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension

Comment: I'm assuming that you're showing that as a trivial example for the purpose of the question, rather as something you actually want to do. However it's the same answer. Just create your own class which "extends String" and put the annotations on that. Instantiate your bean using your annotated class instead of String.

Comment: Good point. :) But presumably you're not actually trying to intercept the instantiation of a String? I can't think of any case when that would not be completely pointless.